# How To Rescue Content from a Corrupt Database

Tags: database

I have spent many weeks inputting content into a commerce system. The database is corrupt. (The website displays fine for an anonymous user, but if you log in you get a blank page. Backups/restore all yield same results) I have now set up a new version of the system, but would like to export/import content and content types from the old system to the new one. How can I do this? Which tables would I need to transfer?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a corrupt DB to me, sounds like white screen of death.

Answer (score 1):

The database isn't likely to be corrupt - unless you're coming up against a ridiculously unlikely scenario, it wouldn't work for any users at all if it was corrupt.

If the data was corrupt, you wouldn't be able to restore the backup, it would fail.

What you need to do is look into the server logs; you're currently seeing a WSOD (White Screen of Death), which is common in PHP applications.

Your server logs will contain details of the exact error your site is encountering, and you can use that information to decide on how to debug and fix it.

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the Watchdog table. Just a "Login attempt failed for %user." and "Session opened for %name." followed by a bunch of "Cron run completed."

Comment: Fatal exceptions won't make it to the watchdog - check your server error logs (nginx/apache/php-fpm/etc)

Comment: I have found var/log/httpd/error_log. The errors in this file are:
[Fri May 13 07:58:00 2016] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 11413 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Fri May 13 08:01:58 2016] [error] [client 180.76.15.152] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/robots.txt
[Fri May 13 08:05:12 2016] [error] server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
[Fri May 13 08:32:28 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri May 13 08:32:30 2016] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)

Answer (score 0):

I installed Drupal, the template and files and the database to a different server and the whole thing worked. The only thing that changed on the old server between it working and not working is an upgrade of PHP. It must be the culprit. Thanks for helping me work through this issue.